# Difference between Asc in VB and charCodeAt in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vba, unicode, ascii

I am currently trying to decode an old encryption that was created and maintained through Visual Basic. The new tool I am creating is using NodeJS for its backend and I am running into an issue with the character codes returned from charCodeAt.

The encryption works like this:
There is a file that holds 3 lines of text, the key, the username, and the password.
The username and password are encrypted using the given key.
To decrypt, first take one of the strings, reverse it, then go character by character through it. Take the numerical code associated with the character and subtract the key's numerical value at that character from it, then take the resulting number and use it as the character for that position of the string.
If the key is shorter than the input string, loop back through the key string as needed.

The problem arises when I am supposed to get a number like 136 (the key being 36 and the decoded character being 100), I end up getting 8221. I think this is because Visual Basic only works off ascii while JS allows for unicode, but I am not sure how to address this and work around it. Any help would be much appreciated!

The Original VB decryption

```
Function Decrypt(str, key)
    Dim lenKey, KeyPos, LenStr, x, Newstr

    Newstr = ""
    lenKey = Len(key)
    KeyPos = 1
    LenStr = Len(str)

    str = StrReverse(str)
    For x = LenStr To 1 Step -1
        Newstr = Newstr & Chr(Asc(Mid(str, x, 1)) - Asc(Mid(key, KeyPos, 1)))
        KeyPos = KeyPos + 1
        If KeyPos > lenKey Then KeyPos = 1
    Next
    Newstr = StrReverse(Newstr)
    Decrypt = Newstr
End Function
```

My Current Attempt at a JS decryption:

```
function decrypt(str, key) {
    str = reverseString(str);
    str = str.split("");
    key = key.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        str[i] = String.fromCharCode(str[i].charCodeAt(0) - key[i % key.length].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    str = str.join("");
    return reverseString(str);
}

function reverseString(str) {
    var splitString = str.split("");
    var reverseArray = splitString.reverse();
    var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
    return joinArray;
}
```

The encrypted file:

> $4yU3Jr#bQ6K
> ”¤Ú´”¼Û‡
> H€kžì”º‡£

The decrypted file:

> $4yU3Jr#bQ6K
> dira_app
> Xg6XqzT88$L$

Comment: Can you post your code and an example of decoded encoded message? because for keyboard letters usually `charCodeAt` and `asc` should be the same

Comment: I had thought they would be the same thing but I keep running into issues with it so I am very confused.

Comment: @Merthew - are you still looking for a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for a solution. I put this on the backburner but it would be good to know since I will need a solution to this or I'll have to brute force it.